# Checking for Collisions with Raycasts - Collider not being registered when it clearly should be

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to implement player movement such that the player can't collide with other collidable objects, such as tiles, but the recasts I'm using aren't registering any other collider when it clearly should be

So the problem I'm trying to solve is to check if there is a collision with a raycast that extends exactly how far the player will move, and get information on the object that was collided with. After that, I would adjust the player's movement accordingly so that the player is not colliding with the object after the raycast finds such a collidable. Here is the source code:

```
// Move body towards a certain direction, by a certain value
protected void MoveBody(Vector3 direction, float speed)
{
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    //int layerMask = 1 << 8; // bit sequence 1000 0000 - Only 'collidable' layer
    RaycastHit hit;

    Vector3 ySize = new Vector3(0, GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.y/2, 0);
    Vector3 startPos = transform.position - ySize;

    if (Physics.Raycast(startPos, direction, out hit, speed * Time.deltaTime))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(startPos, direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, Color.yellow);
        Debug.Log("Did Hit");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(startPos, direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, Color.yellow);
        Debug.Log("Did Not Hit");
    }


    // Update gameObject's transform.position here based on whether a collidable was found
}
```

When I run the game, the first frame ensures that the raycast is colliding with another box collider, as shown by this image: [image: img]

The expected Debug.Log would be "Did hit", but it's logging "Did not hit". The yellow line shows the full raycast, and it's clearly intersecting the box collider of the tile below the purple man.

The MoveBody function is being run each frame to simulate gravity (I omitted the part where the object falls so the player object just stays in place for the entire time), but as you can see, the raycast never registers a collision. Both player and tile1 have a box collider, so I don't understand what's going on. Would really appreciate any help I can get!!! Thanks!

Comment: You are using a 3D Raycast with 2D Colliders - they aren't compatible. Either use [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)  or use 3D colliders on your entities

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!!

Comment: Hey, if that works for you, please write it as an answer and accept it. Would be good i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Physics.Raycast, but I should have been using Physics2D.Raycast, as my Unity game is in 2D. Physics.Raycast isn't compatible with 2D Unity games.